# Individual Name Fields are not available when adding a new contact

Tags: contacts, fields, missing

I recently migrated my CiviCRM 4.4.10lts that was running on Joomla to a fresh 5.12.4 install on Drupal 7.66. The LAMP is an Ubuntu 18.04 stack on Azure.

[image: Screenshot]

I had to copy my data into the new database manually because of errors in the Cases component that prevented me from upgrading and my old host upgraded their MySql server to a version not supported by my version.

Now, none of the individual name fields are available when creating new individual contacts. If I add a new contact record using the New Individual block it creates a contact without a name. When viewing an existing contact record the names are there but if I attempt to edit them with either the inline editor or the normal contact edit function the names disappear.

There are no errors being thrown in either Drupal or CiviCRM and I have the same results with any theme I use.

I suspect I accidentally overwrote something in one of the tables while moving data but have no idea where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What about creating new Organisation? just trying to help you fathom what more might be borked. ditto Households.

Comment: They are both fine. It seems to only be the the individual name fields that are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Editing contact options are listed from option groups named 'Contact Edit Options'. Check if the options are present in the 'Contact Edit Options' option group. If not then adding options should fix the problem. Unfortunately the UI doesn't allow you at add a new option. But you can add it through api/explorer screen of CiviCRM.

[image]

Note: Option Name should be the field name same as column name in civicrm_contact table eg first_name, last_name, middle_name etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. Aparently when I imported the Option Groups from my old site I truncated those values. Had I upgraded 4.5.alpha1.mysql.tpl would have added them automatically. Hopefully I don't have any more surprises like that. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a cv command to search for and add missing fields? I just noticed the environment fields are missing also.

Answer (score 0):

Check your profiles - the fields on the new individual form are profile driven - you can see what profiles should be on a new site on the demo site https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/uf/group?reset=1&selectedChild=reserved-profiles

Comment: You are right that New Individual is a Profile, but the screenshot, with all the missing Individual Name Fields, is not Profile driven afaik.

Comment: if you look at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1 you will see it lists; Prefix, Format Title, First Name etc etc. Fact these are not showing suggests something much deeper is the problem