# Name and Telephone Number Fields are not displayed when trying to add an individual

Tags: fields

Apparently, after upgrading to CiviCRM Version 5.58.1, the Name and Telephone number fields are not presented when attempting to add an individual contact.  The telephone number field is available when viewing the record, but not when doing a whole record edit.

I see this response to a similar question: [Individual Name Fields are not available when adding a new contact](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30452/individual-name-fields-are-not-available-when-adding-a-new-contact)

However, that doens't seem to help me in any way.

Is there a way for a mere mortal to fix this via some simple setting under the Administrator console?  I can't seem to find anything that will control this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kent - welcome. could you add a couple of screenshots and / or confirm same behaviour on one of the demo sites, eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the fields are not included in Editing Contacts options at CiviCRM >> Adminsiter >> Customize data and screen >> Display preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I've got one site on 5.58.1 and it's showing me this when I add a new individual:

[image]

Sadly, I did nothing to achieve this. I looked at the reserved profile (Under Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Profiles) for new individual and it only shows First, Last, Email. Maybe you could add the additional fields there?

[image]

Kathryn